# String to Datetime Conversion in Ajax CalendarExtender.

Tags: sql, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, type-conversion

**In Calender Control :** when I select Date, it is display in TextBox in this format : ***15-06-2015 00:00:00 means "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss".***

After that I converted TextBox text into DateTime datatype using

> DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);

and store into database.

In database it store in this format : ***2015-06-15 means "yyyy-mm-dd"* because column datatype is Date.**

**In Ajax CalendarExtender** : Now I am using CalendarExtender from AjexControlToolkit. I don't use format attribute. By default it display in textbox in this format : ***6/16/2015 menas "mm/dd/yyyy"***

try to convert Textbox string to datetime datatype using same code

> DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);

but error is displayed that ***"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"***

Even I also try

> DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text);

but same error is displayed every time.

Comment: you can set format property `Format="yyyy-mm-dd"`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, provide the Format attribute for the AJAX control or use `DateTime.ParseExact`.

```
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
    TargetControlID="Date1"
    CssClass="ClassName"
    Format="yyyy-MM-dd"
    PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```

http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Using `ParseExact`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("6/16/2015", "M/dd/yyyy", null);
```